# My chrome passwords get reset when I restart my computer

Tags: google-chrome, browser, passwords, sync, brave

I noticed that whenever restart my computer and then launch chrome, I won't be signed in at the top right, so I click the circle at the top right to sign in to my profile and I sign in and sync is on.

Then the weird part is, even after I sign in and sync is on, I am not only not automatically signing in the pages I visit every day, chrome is also not auto-filling any password boxes for me. not for my Gmail or YouTube or any site. When I view my password manager for my Google account, all the passwords are there, and they are the correct passwords I checked. Those sync ones don't go away.

[image: password manager]

My chrome only starts auto signing in the pages and auto-filling passwords into forms when I can see them in my actual browser settings here:

[image: Browser passwords]

As you can see there are much fewer things in here than in the synced passwords in the password manager. These only appear after I sign in the stuff by typing in my password but disappear when I restart my computer.

So why doesn't my chrome just use the passwords that are already in the password manager when I signed in if sync is turned on? Or somehow import those into the browser. It's like they are saved but it doesn't actually do anything with them.

I noticed brave also doesn't save my passwords which is why I moved back to chrome but the problem followed me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by going to Settings > Sync and Google services > Data from Chrome sync > Reset Sync (at the bottom of the page).